# C# Progress Reporting

Tags: c#

The following code fails to compile:

```
async Task Foo (Action<int> onProgressPercentChanged)
{
    return Task.Run (() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 10 == 0) onProgressPercentChanged (i / 10);

        }
    });
}
```

due to the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1997  Since 'Nutshell.Foo(Action)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task'?

but this is done exactly as shown in the book. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `return` you should `await` your `Task.Run` statement

```
async Task Foo(Action<int> action)
{
    await Task.Run(() => /*...*/);
}
```

or, if you prefer to return `Task`, you should not mark the method as `async`

```
Task Foo(Action<int> action)
{
    return Task.Run(() => /*...*/);
}
```

Comment: Thank tdragon, tried it and it worked. Normally when code that will not compile is illustrated in the book, it is indicated that it will not. This time however, it wasn't.

Answer (score 8):

Your method is marked `async Task`, so the compiler expects it to not return anything. If you want to return a task, then you should not mark the method `async`. Alternatively, you could use `await` inside the `async` method.

```
// Option 1
Task Foo (Action<int> onProgressPercentChanged)
{
  return Task.Run (() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      if (i % 10 == 0) onProgressPercentChanged (i / 10);
    }
  });
}

// Option 2
async Task Foo (Action<int> onProgressPercentChanged)
{
  await Task.Run (() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      if (i % 10 == 0) onProgressPercentChanged (i / 10);
    }
  });
}
```

For more about the difference between these two, see my blog post on [eliding async](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

On to the other problems...

**Use the progress reporting built-in to .NET instead of rolling your own.**

.NET uses the `IProgress<T>` type, so you can just use that:

```
Task Foo (IProgress<int> progress = null)
{
  return Task.Run (() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      if (progress != null && i % 10 == 0) progress.Report(i / 10);
    }
  });
}
```

By following the progress conventions, we allow callers to *not* request progress updates, and we also allow a very natural marshalling to the UI thread using `Progress<T>`:

```
// Caller, from UI thread
var progress = new Progress<int>(report =>
{
  // Handle progress report. This code is already on the UI thread! :)
});
await Foo(progress);
```

**Don't use `Task.Run` in the implementation; use `Task.Run` to call the method.** [Using `Task.Run` to implement fake-asynchronous methods is an antipattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/). I write more about this [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) as well.

Applying this fix makes `Foo` synchronous, which is exactly correct since it does no actual asynchronous work:

```
void Foo(IProgress<int> progress = null)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    if (progress != null && i % 10 == 0) progress.Report(i / 10);
  }
}

// Caller
var progress = new Progress<int>(report => ...);
await Task.Run(() => Foo(progress));
```

And finally, **don't throttle progress reports at the source; throttle them at the receiver**. If your code ever runs on different CPUs, then any throttling you do at the source (`i % 10`) is going to be problematic. It's better to use an `IProgress<T>` implementation that throttles.

This nicely simplifies your code to:

```
void Foo(IProgress<int> progress = null)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    if (progress != null) progress.Report(i / 10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove **return** statement in method. Your method shouldn't return anything.

Comment: Better to remove `async` before the method.